# How to redirect to separate files and to a combined file?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

It's easy to redirect standard output and standard error to the same file or to separate files.  What if I want to do both at the same time?  That is, I'd like three files as output: standard output and standard input mixed together in order and standard output and standard error in separate files.  Maybe something involving the "tee" command?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rob, as part of your question, see if you can provide the code that you have attempted already.  By the way, I think your idea of using `tee` is a step in the right direction.

Comment: You can use redirect stuff e.g. `echo "hello" >>combinedfile&> singlefile`, you can use a combination of 2&1 etc. and just build up your output using these constructs

Comment: @RobSteele: You find plenty of examples, including your use case, in the  [Advanced bash scripting guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: @user1934428 Perhaps you could point out the example you think is relevant.

Comment: It's where it says _Error messages get sent to same place as standard output._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following ideas in comments, use tee to place stdout/stderr into specific file, and into combined file.

```
rm -f both.log
some-command 2> >(tee err.log >>both.log) | tee out.log >> both.log
```

Comment: Add (...) to avoid having to mention both.log twice:
`(some-command 2> >(tee err) > >(tee out)) > both`